# Is there a sql command to delete the files on HDFS for an external table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I would ask if there is a sql command in hive to drop the table and delete the files on hdfs for this external table.

When I use hdfs command to delete the files, I am always afraid that I may delete other files that doesn't belong to this external table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such sql command to drop external table directly but there is an alternative

1. First make this table as managed:
2. Drop the table

Step 1 :

```
ALTER TABLE <table-name> SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='False');
```

Step 2 :

```
 drop table <table-name>; //now the table is internal if you drop the table data will be dropped automatically.
```